# How can I manage (or pass as an argument) my config json to start the testing of my vertx application?

Tags: java, json, vert.x

I have a small vertx application with an AppLauncher class that extend of VertxCommandLauncher and I set a appConfig.json with the typical config parameters :

```
public class AppLauncher extends VertxCommandLauncher implements VertxLifecycleHooks {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppLauncher().dispatch(args);
}

@Override
public void afterConfigParsed(JsonObject config) {
    AppConfig.INSTANCE.setConfig(config);
}
```

To run my application in my IDE I put in edit configuration my main class (Applauncher.java) and the arguments :

```
run io.vertx.covid.verticle.MainVerticle -conf../vertx-application/src/main/resources/appConfig.json
```

This is my test class:

```
@BeforeAll
 static void deployVerticles(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    
    vertx.deployVerticle(BaseVerticle.class.getName(),testContext
      .succeeding(id->testContext.completeNow()));
}
```

This is my BaseVerticle class that all my verticles extends from:

```
public abstract class BaseVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  public static String CONTEXT_PATH =   AppConfig.INSTANCE.getConfig().getString(Constants.CONTEXT_PATH);
```

}

And this is my AppConfig class :

```
public enum AppConfig {
INSTANCE;
private JsonObject config;

public JsonObject getConfig() {
    return config;
}

public void setConfig(JsonObject config) {
    this.config = config;
}
```

}

Everything works, but if I would like to test it in a separete way then I  deploy my verticles but I have a **Nullpointer** in the CONTEXT_PATH (BaseVerticle class) because the config (suppose to be taken from appConfig.json) is null.
I haven't found a way to pass the arguments with my appConfig.json or should I call to the main method passing the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I like to do something that is similar to profiles in my vertx application.

If you set an environment variable with the key `vertx-config-path` before the vertx instance is initialized, you can control where vertx's config retriever (you might need to add vert-config to your gradle/maven dependencies) gets the configuration from.

In your launcher, you can do something like the following, which will give you the ability to add profile based config files to your resources folder `conf/config-%s.json` where `%s` is the profile name:

```java
public class CustomLauncher extends Launcher {
  public static final String ACTIVE_PROFILE_PROPERTY = "APP_ACTIVE_PROFILE";

  private static final CLI cli = CLI.create("main")
    .addOption(new Option()
      .setShortName("p")
      .setLongName("profile")
    );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    initDefaults(Arrays.asList(args));
    new CustomLauncher().dispatch(args);
  }

  public static void executeCommand(String cmd, String... args) {
    initDefaults(Arrays.asList(args));
    new CustomLauncher().execute(cmd, args);
  }

  public static void initDefaults(List<String> args) {
    System.setProperty(LoggerFactory.LOGGER_DELEGATE_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME, SLF4JLogDelegateFactory.class.getName());

    CommandLine parse = cli.parse(args);
    String profile = parse.getOptionValue("p");
    if (profile != null && !profile.isEmpty()) {
      System.setProperty(ACTIVE_PROFILE_PROPERTY, profile);
      System.setProperty("vertx-config-path", String.format("conf/config-%s.json", profile));
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your test, instead of relaying on vertx test extension to inject vertx for you, you can initialize it by yourself and control the profile (aka which config file to load) like the following:

```java
private static Vertx vertx;

@BeforeAll
public static void deployVerticles(VertxTestContext testContext) {
  CustomLauncher.initDefaults(Arrays.asList("--profile", "test"))
  vertx = Vertx.vertx();

  ConfigRetriever.create(vertx).getConfig(asyncResult -> {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
      JsonObject config = asyncResult.result();
      DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
        .setConfig(config);

      vertx.deployVerticle(BaseVerticle.class.getName(), deploymentOptions);
    } else {
      // handle failure
    }
  });
}
```

Then when you run your application, instead of providing -conf, you can use `-p` or `--profile`

I also highly recommend to get familiar with vertx-config as you can also get env variables, k8s config maps, and much more.

**EDIT:** I also highly recommend to move to Kotlin if possible, makes the async-code much easier to handle in an imperative way (with Coroutines). It's very hard to deal with libraries like Vert.x in Java compared to languages like Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you @Tom.
"set an environment variable with the key vertx-config-path before the vertx instance is initialized," Do you mean in my appConfig.json or maybe Should I use in an Override method from VertxCommandLauncher? , for instance:
 Override
    public void beforeStartingVertx(VertxOptions vertxOptions) {

    }
 Override
    public void beforeDeployingVerticle(DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions) {

    }

Comment: @mononoke83 You can see in the test i do it before doing `vertx = Vertx.vertx();`. When you run the application using the vertx custom launcher it will set it for you if you use the `-p` or `--profile` arguments (you can see it in the `initDefaults()` method i added). In general this environment variable can be set in various ways, just make sure that you set it before anything calls to `Vertx.vertx()` - aka before vertx is first initialized as this env variable is being used when vertx is initialized

Comment: Still not working, I've edited my question adding my BaseVerticle class  maybe I did some wrong. I've follow your steps and I got the same nullPointer in the same line :
 public static String CONTEXT_PATH =   AppConfig.INSTANCE.getConfig().getString(Constants.CONTEXT_PATH);

Comment: If you do it from the verticle it is to late. You need to set the property in the launcher, then use the `ConfigRetriever` to get your config (`ConfigRetriever.create(vertx).getConfig(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem creating a verticle with the config stuffs (vertx-config documentation), here is my verticle config class:

```
 public class ConfigVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigVerticle.class);
  public static JsonObject config;

      @Override
      public void start() throws Exception {
        ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions()
          .setType("file")
          .setOptional(true)
          .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", "conf/appConfig.json"));
        ConfigStoreOptions sysPropsStore = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("sys");
    
        ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(fileStore).addStore(sysPropsStore);
    
        ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);
    
        retriever.getConfig(ar -> {
          if (ar.failed()) {
            logger.info("Failed to retrieve config from appConfig.json");
          } else {
            config = ar.result();
            vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config));
          }
        });
      }
    
    }
```

And my MainVerticle.class I pass the new configuration like this:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

@Override
public void start(){

  vertx.deployVerticle(BackendVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config()));

}
```

}

Then, my simpleTests :

```
    @ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
 public class BaseCovidTest {

  protected WebClient webClient;

  @BeforeEach
  void initWebClient(Vertx vertx){
    webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
  }



 @BeforeAll
  static void deployVerticles(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext vertxTestContext) {

vertx.deployVerticle(ConfigVerticle.class.getName() ,vertxTestContext
  .succeeding(id-> {
    try {
      vertxTestContext.awaitCompletion(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    vertxTestContext.completeNow();
  }));

 }

}
```

And everything works, thanks @Tom that inspired me to fix it!